# Can I instantiate a template pipeline with a list of values?

Tags: azure-devops

We have the following Azure DevOps pipeline template:

```
- stage: DeployToPreprod
  displayName: 'Deploy to PREPROD'
  dependsOn: PrepareDeployToPreprod
  condition: not(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: SRV-SAF
        targetHostDisplayName: SRV_SAF
        targetEnv: PREPROD
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: DT1CTX003
        targetHostDisplayName: DT1CTX003
        targetEnv: PREPROD
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: DT1CTX004
        targetHostDisplayName: DT1CTX004
        targetEnv: PREPROD
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: VDA-PROD-R01
        targetHostDisplayName: VDA_PROD_R01
        targetEnv: PREPROD
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: VDA-PROD-R02
        targetHostDisplayName: VDA_PROD_R02
        targetEnv: PREPROD
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: VDA-PROD-R03
        targetHostDisplayName: VDA_PROD_R03
        targetEnv: PREPROD
    - template: Scripts/deploy.yaml
      parameters:
        targetHost: VDA-PROD-R04
        targetHostDisplayName: VDA_PROD_R04
        targetEnv: PREPROD
```

As one can easily sees, this is basically instantiating the same template with a list of different machine names. Is there a way to remove some duplication and instantiate the template several times giving it a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove some duplication and instantiate the template several times giving it a list?

The answer is yes.

You could use the [strategy and matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops) to resolve this question:

```
- stage: DeployToPreprod
  displayName: 'Deploy to PREPROD'
  dependsOn: PrepareDeployToPreprod
  condition: not(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
  - job: Dev
    displayName: Dev
    pool:
     name: MyPrivateAgent

    strategy: 
      matrix:
        dev_1:
          targetHost: SRV-SAF
          targetHostDisplayName: SRV_SAF
          targetEnv: PREPROD
        dev_2:
          targetHost: DT1CTX003
          targetHostDisplayName: DT1CTX003
          targetEnv: PREPROD

     - template: child.yml #change this to your Scripts/deploy.yaml file
       parameters:
         targetHost: $(targetHost)
         targetHostDisplayName: $(targetHostDisplayName)
         targetEnv: $(targetEnv)
```

The `Child.yml`:

```
parameters:
- name: targetHost 
  type: string 
  default: false

- name: targetHostDisplayName 
  type: string 
  default: false

- name: targetEnv 
  type: string 
  default: false

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.targetHost }}
  displayName: 'targetHost'

- script: echo ${{ parameters.targetHostDisplayName }}
  displayName: 'targetHostDisplayName'

- script: echo ${{ parameters.targetEnv }}
  displayName: 'targetEnv'
```

The result:

[image]

Hope this helps.